# Infinite Noetherian ring of dimension $1$ in which distinct non-zero ideals have distinct and finite index

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, integral-extensions, dimension-theory-algebra

Let $R$ be an infinite commutative ring with unity such that every non-zero ideal has finite index. Then $R$ is Noetherian, every non-zero prime ideal is maximal , and I can also show that $R$ is an integral domain.  Now also assume that  distinct ideals have distinct index; then is it true that $R$ is a UFD, or at least normal (integrally closed in its fraction field) ?

(note: $\dim R \le 1$ , now if $\dim R=0$, then $R$ is an Artinian domain, so a field. So w.l.o.g., assume $R$ has dimension $1$  )

Comment: Cross-posted to MO here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/320068/infinite-noetherian-ring-of-dimension-1-in-which-distinct-non-zero-ideals-have